# Facebook Graph API logout doesn't work

Tags: actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api

Using the Facebook Actionscript Graph API to upload videos to a user's facebook page
http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/

When first logging in after a user has entered their name and password, a 2nd modal appears asking permission to post to the user's friends pages.

The problem is, if the user hits cancel, the application in effect becomes broken because they remain logged in and the next user will be presented with the same 2nd privacy modal and NOT the first username password modal.

I tried calling logout

```
FacebookDesktop.logout(callback, <APP-ORIGIN_URL>)
```

but that doesn't seem to log the user out right away. The user session seems to be stored on the server as well since I cannot locate any LSO's (Flash cookies)

Can anyone help?

Comment: This lib has errors, probably should checkout the JSBridge ...

Comment: Yeah never had much success with the logout calls. Never seems to work completely.